# Banner Slider not centering in html

Tags: jquery, slider

I added a jQuery responsive slider to my page, and instead of being centered in the page, the slider is shifted to the right of the page..I tried everything in CSS to get it centered, but I could not. I cannot find what I am doing wrong here, can someone point out the mistake?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuspL501/)

here is my code

```
<div class="banner">

        <div class="slider">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> <img src="graphics/top.jpg" width="990" height="520"> </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> <img src="graphics/top.jpg" width="990" height="520"> </a> </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dots">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="0" class="cur"></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1"></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="2"></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="3"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-left">&lt;</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-right">&gt;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.banner { margin-bottom: 20px; z-index: 1; }
.banner .slider { position: relative; width: 990px; }
.banner .slider ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; width: 100%; height: 520px; position: relative;}
.banner .slider ul li { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; }
.banner .slider .dots:after { display: table; clear: both; content: ""; }
.banner .slider .dots { position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 60%; z-index: 40; *zoom: 1; }
.banner .slider .dots a { display: block; float: left; width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-right: 10px; text-indent: -9999em; background: #000; border-radius: 10px; }
.banner .slider .dots .cur { background: #329; }
.banner .slider .arrow { width: 65%; position: absolute; top: 45%; left: 18%; z-index: 50; }
.banner .slider .arrow a { font-family: "Microsoft YaHei"; font-size: 34px; font-weight: 700; color: #fff; }
.banner .slider .arrow .btn-left { float: left; }
.banner .slider .arrow .btn-right { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.banner { position: absolute; margin-left:-495px; left:50%; width: 990px;}` and remove `.banner .slider ul li { left: 50%; }`

That should center it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DeadEli/7gLgpbdc/)